# PHP Error message is comming like Undefined index: RadioGroup1 in C:\wamp\www\TEMPLATE\fileDisposalResults.php on line 4

Tags: php

Im selecting a radio button from radio group..but when i click the button it will get a error like this
Undefined index: RadioGroup1 in C:\wamp\www\TEMPLATE\fileDisposalResults.php on line 3

```
if(isset($_POST['h1'])  &&  $_POST['h1']=='h1' )
{ //Posting from a hiddne field
    $selected_radio="";
    $selected_radio = $_POST['RadioGroup1'];    
    if ($selected_radio == 'radioDelete') 
    {
        if (isset($_POST['checkbox']))
        {
            $check_ids = $_POST['checkbox'];
            if (is_array($check_ids) && count($check_ids) > 0)
            {
                // $sql="DELETE FROM retained_file_mst  WHERE file_serial_id  IN(".implode(',', $check_ids).")";
                // mysql_query($sql,$conn);
                echo "yesssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you send your form data using POST method? Provide the form html please.

Answer (score 0):

When debugging forms ALWAYS start with:

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```

There is no magic involved.

$_POST is a superglobal that contains what the browser sent (assuming you used METHOD="POST").

Simply check its contents. In 90% of the cases you won't need us. ;-)

Comment: Or just do `print_r ( $_REQUEST );`

Comment: I dislike all usage of $_REQUEST because the developer should know what he is doing (POST or GET or SESSION). These superglobals differ so wildly in their usage that, in my humble opinion, $_REQUEST should never have been added to the language.

Comment: `$_REQUEST` shows it's potential, if you have 1 function handling file that works with both, $_POST and $_GET variables. It helps you not to create two different files for the same procedure and you also don't need extra parameters, to determine, wheather it's a POST or GET request.